# alert the user with remote notification only if the app open and visible?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

When I send a push notification to an application, the application gets the notification whether it's opened or closed.

Can I show the notification to the user ONLY if the app is both open and visible?
So if the app is closed/not visible, I don't want to alert the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called a "silent notification".

Just change your JSON Payload from:

```
{
"aps" : {
    "alert" : "YAP",
    "badge" : 2,
    "sound" : "sound.aiff"
         }
}
```

to

```
{
"aps" : {
    "content-available" : 1,
    "sound" : ""
        }
}
```

More here:

http://www.g8production.com/post/72656082173/ios7-multitasking-silent-notifications

Or here:

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/backgrounding/part_3_ios_backgrounding_techniques/updating_an_application_in_the_background/

Comment: god bless Apple engineers.
may Facebook engineers will learn how to make the developer happy like them.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
   if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground)
   {
   //when your app is at background, notification comes here. You can write here code whatever do you want to do notification
   }
}
```

Also you can control when your app is at active or inactive, don't forget add UIApplicationDelegate.

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification is only called when the user PRESSES the notification! Unless it's a silent notification, the it gets auto-accepted.

Comment: but he doesn't want to silent all of them, he just wants to send notification only active state

Comment: Ok, but your solution will still show an alert the user if he's in background.

Comment: Ok, I understood now. Thank you to improve my answer